# Networkx for drawing edges between two edges

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to draw a graph of a set of nodes (vertices) that are connected by edges (links). There is a dependency between the edges and it should be represented in the graph to represent the calculation of the algorithm to the end-user.

Example: The red arrows denote dependency of edges. For example, edge BC depends on edge AB:

[image: example]

How can I draw this using Networkx?

Comment: If edges have a dependency relationship, they are themselves nodes in (another?) graph.

Comment: Hi @Sam, this is the start of a good question: can you add some code to show what you've tried already?

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1, thank you for your comment. It will be easy if I will consider the edges as nodes. But it will not represent the real situation that I have and it will make a big confusion for the end-users. I do not think this will work

Comment: Hi @EliotK, thank you for going through my question. I have tried to use Networkx documentation, but I do believe the library does not support such plotting. I searched also online for any ideas, but nothing helped.  I do appreciate any help. Thanks in advance